# Flag abuse in chat

Tags: discussion, chat, flags

I've seen two or three users flagging my messages in different chat rooms which is absurd. Take this as an example:

[image]

Then

[image]

It seems they're flagged out of dislike for me, or the one who flags doesn't speak English. I'm sick of this behaviour and I think they should be warned, if not suspended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A flag like that will obviously get handled as "invalid", since there's nothing spammy or offensive about your message. (Caveat: I didn't look at the context.)

Unfortunately there's no way to tell *who* flagged it, so there's not much anybody can do about it except dismiss as "invalid" and move on.

I'm sorry that your messages are getting targeted this way, but at least you're not likely to get chat-suspended over it, since the flags don't make any sense.

Comment: The context is that picture, I didn't talk in that room since last month or something. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Anna, so do users see their own flags? What's the value in this exactly? It seems like this should harass moderators more than a user.

Comment: @jmort253 Chat flags are notoriously problematic to handle because it's difficult to judge context in most cases. There are two kinds of flags, one that shows who flagged and one that doesn't (similar to how post flags work). Also chat flags are pretty rare. So it kinda balances out in the end (most of the time).

Comment: @jmort253 I actually have no idea if users see their own flags. Pretty sure flags are shown to all SE users with over 10k rep (except for moderator-only flags), but I'm hazy on how all of it works, to be honest.

Comment: @AnnaLear - Just FYI, Gigili's [highest rep](http://stackexchange.com/users/382048/gigili?tab=accounts) is just under 3000 on launched sites and just under 1000 on beta sites; thus, she isn't a 10k (or beta 2k). Hope this helps!

Comment: @jmort253: JFYI, I'm a 10k user. 10.5k, to be exact.

Comment: @Gigili - Odd, your 10k account doesn't show up in your list of accounts... Not sure why...

Comment: @jmort253 Is that not a 10k total for Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Bart - I guess that would make sense, assuming that the chat 10k moderation tools take into account the rep on all accounts and not just the highest. Normally, when we say "10k user" we usually mean 10k on a single site... (Also, I had no idea there were 10k tools in chat, but that's another question altogether)

Comment: @jmort253: What Bart said. It's the overall rep, not just one site.

Comment: @anna i've seen a chat flag against me in the past, but cant say if it's the same for regular users